# Gaussian based clustering/partitioning, does it make sense with not much data?

Tags: clustering, gaussian-process, anderson-darling-test

I have a dataset about hourly aggregated mobile phone usage (#calls, #sms, #internetConnections) in one mobile cell. For example I have this data about activity at 8:00am:

```
[date] [#calls] [#sms] [#internetConnections]
```

The company I collaborate with wants to create a model for the data, and successively identify abnormal use at a specific time[*].  In order to do so, I thought about this process:

1. Test the hyphothesis "The data are sampled from a Gaussian" (with [Anderson-Darling test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35e.htm))
2. Test the hyphothesis "The data are NOT sampled from a Gaussian" (with [Anderson-Darling test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35e.htm))
3. If it accept H0 and reject H1, it means that a Gaussian model represents the data. If it rejects H0 and accept H1, I continue with step 4
4. I try to partition the data (eg. "data in the weekends" - "data in the working dats").
5. I go to point 1 and I test each partition

Now the questions are:

- does it make sense? (in general)
- This process implies the validity of the central limit theorem (right?), so if I end up creating a partition with 80 points (in point 4.), the resulting model could not make sense, couldn't it?

*Notes:
[*] now they use two models: weekend-weekdays. If some data-point is not sampled from a Gaussian, is abnormal. They want to improve this model.*

Comment: It is hard to see how the question of whether the "data around the center" (whatever that means!) are Gaussian has any bearing on abnormal usage. It is also hard to see how the CLT has any bearing on phone usage, either (and it is certainly not the case that phone usage tells us anything about the CLT!). If you want to identify "abnormal use," then you first need to characterize normal use--*whatever it might be.* And normal use very likely does not exhibit Gaussian distributions of anything.

Comment: @whuber I fixed the "around the center", sorry. 
CLT: If I estimate the Gaussian distribution from 80 points, this model is weak, isn't it? I mean if the 81st point is different, it's abnormal for THIS estimation, but maybe with 3000 points it would be normal. (Am I right?)
anyway: this company says that normal = Gaussian distributed data. What would you think instead?